# Extract tweets with specific words in python list. sentimnt analysis

Tags: python, list, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I have tweets stored in python list
like

1. COVID vaccine allergic reactions polyethylene glycol hypothesized possible culprit I kind skeptical science fit well VaccinesWork VaccinesSaveLives
2. COVIDー COVID MaskeAuf vaccine Impfstart Impfstoff
3. M people died hunger There vaccine called food It works straight away w one dose harmful side effects Let cure hunger worry virus w survival rate w vaccine vaccine covid hunger etc..

and I have most comman words like Covid, Vaccine etc..

I need to get all tweets with specific words. assume I stored words in new list like

```
word_= "Covid"
```

and I have new empty list named new_list to append the tweets

```
for tweets in list_tweets:
    if word in list_tweets:
     new_list.append(list_tweets)
```

but I got nothing. any help , suggestions. I be so appreciated

Comment: you are not checking if a word is there in any tweet, you are checking if a word is there in tweet list (that means you check if there is a tweet with just one word say Covid), thats why you dont get any answer.
Change `if word in list_tweets:` to `if word in tweets:` .You might need case insenstive comparison also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if word in list_tweets` checks if one element of the `list_tweets` is `"Covid"` (or any value contained in `word`)

I think you want to check `if word in tweets` instead.

ps : naming your variable `tweet` instead of `tweets`would be a good idea, since it takes values from a list of tweets (thus is a single tweet)